# How to resolve a conflict while merging two branches of a repo through a fork?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I'm in the middle of some weird Git mess.

This is the situation right now - 
In my team's Git repo we are trying to merge from `develop` to `release` - we are getting a conflict in one of the files.

The process I am bound with is - All development PRs from engineers' fork is first merged to `develop` and then it is merged to `release` from which it is then rolled out.

So I tried to fetch the upstream (team's repo) in my fork which was up-to date with develop and merged it with `release` and pushed it to my fork branch. No conflicts. Raised a PR against `develop` as is the process. But the conflict from develop to release still exists.
How to go about fixing it?

Edit - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZs9.jpg Thought this image would help simplify what I am struggling with.

P.S - I tried to provide as much info in the best possible way.

Comment: There shouldn't be any merge conflicts between `develop` and `release`, as `release` should always be being merged back to `develop`, and work should only be committed to `develop`. The only thing `release` should ever receive is updated copies of `develop`. The complication comes from adding a fork into the equation. But the question is why such a fork exists in the first place? If you're all in the same team, why aren't you committing to the same repo? And has development occurred on both the fork and the original?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Every engineer works with a forked copy of `develop` - builds a feature and then submits a PR to `develop`. Does it help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

> Every engineer works with a forked copy of develop

Then, before submitting a PR, they should:

- fetch from upstream (the remote name for the original repository they have forked), to have an up-to-date version of develop: upstream/develop
- rebase they work on top of upstream/develop (ignoring a local develop branch)
- re-submit their PR.

Even if they has already made the PR, they can still go through that process, and then force push their PR branch: their existing PR will be automatically updated.

Comment: You are right @VonC. I did the same process. Although conflict arises when we try to raise the PR from develop to release. Think this image would help https://imgur.com/45aPxk2 simplify.